# Endiannes of machine and array elements storing

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, endianness

I am concerned about how arrays are stored in C. for example I have such array:

```cpp
unsigned char array[] = {1, 0};
```

I have Little endian machine so as far as I know elements of this array will be stored in memory in reversed order like [0, 1].

But when i execute such code :

```cpp
std::cout << (void*)&array[0] << std::endl;
std::cout << (void*)&array[1] << std::endl;
```

I will get two addresses. The second one will be bigger by one.

I don't understand this because if the 0 element will be placed first in memory and then 1, so why the address of first element of array (value 1) is lesser than second element (value 0).

Comment: Endianness relates to the byte order for integers of 2 or more bytes. It doesn't apply for single byte types like the `char`s.

Comment: But when i will cast this array for e.g. to short:

```c++
short a = *(short*)array;
```

The value of a will be 1. So it looks like 1 was stored after 0.

Comment: `*(short*)array;` is undefined behavior, you aren't allowed to do that. The result isn't guaranteed and anything can happen. Including producing the result 1. But if you `memcpy` it to a `short` then it depends on your platform. But that's not what you are showing here, endianness doesn't matter for a `unsigned char[2]`.

Comment: Endianness doesn't matter for array indexes. They are always guaranteed to increasing in terms of memory address, i.e. `&arr[0]` is always lesser than than `&arr[1]`. And the first element in the array is guaranteed to be the one which is first in your initializer list. Endianness only matters for order of bytes in longer-than-byte integrals (and some times people talk about endianness of bits, but that's not something which can be exposed from C++).

Comment: I have found such examples in this article: https://developer.ibm.com/articles/au-endianc/

Comment: @Sielan A lot of people do it, but they are probably wrong unless the context is specific to a platform which allows it. If they are doing it in a portable or generic context (without specifying otherwise) they are completely wrong in doing it.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux you mean endianness of bits? If you are developing C++ code, you can't really access individual bits by their real indexes, so the talk is moot. But if you do, for example, hardware communication on I2C bus, the information on which bit comes first in a byte - most significant or least significant - is important enough.

Comment: @Sielan: even your link has it: `Endianness only makes sense when you’re breaking up a multi-byte quantity and are trying to store the bytes at consecutive memory locations.` It says nothing about arrays.

Comment: @SergeyA This example which they used with array broke my mind :)

Comment: @Sielan That article is written for C, not C++. They are different languages with different rules and it may be that everything there is true **for C**. They may share a common origin, but they evolved as separate languages. It's important not to confuse them.

Comment: There are many ways this can go wrong. The byte array may not be aligned correctly for access as a `short` (fix with `memcpy`). The endian may not be correct (fix with bitshifting or `htons`). The writer and reader may have a differently-sized `short` (Fix by using fixed width integer types).